# Is there any way to increase recursion levels limit in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, limit

It is well known that being careless when writing SQL triggers can lead to a following problem:

```
ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded
```

When I look for this problem solutions, all of them are simple: fix your code because it has issues. And in all cases it turns out to be a good advice.

But *for the academic purposes*: is there any way to increase this maximum number? I see that sometimes it is refered as:

```
maximum number of recursive SQL levels (string) exceeded
```

So maybe there is a way to put your own value under this `string`?

Comment: Where are you encountering this?

Comment: @GordonLinoff In a totally abstract example where I do looped recursion on purpose. I literally have to find a way to control recursive levels value for my academic course :) It's not a real-life situation, I just want to know if there is a way of controlling this parameter.

Comment: Recursion in what?  A CTE?  Function?  Procedure?  Trigger?

Comment: Like I said in a question: "when writing SQL triggers" :) Here is an example:

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER recursion_test
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON users
    FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, district_id)
    VALUES ('John', 'McDummy', 111);

END;
/

It stops at 50 levels. And the question is: can we manipulate this limit or is it hardcoded?

Comment: "When writing a trigger" doesn't specify what is causing the problem.  Triggers can have recursive CTEs, function calls, and stored procedure calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, depends. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/logical-database-limits.html#GUID-685230CF-63F5-4C5A-B8B0-037C566BDA76) says

> Trigger Cascade Limit: Operating system-dependent, typically 32